# MySQL signal duplicate key error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table, which includes an ENUM field. I would like for a particular value of ENUM to require uniqueness with the reference ID column. So let's say I have this:

```
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`type` ENUM('single','multi') NOT NULL,
`refid` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`extra` TEXT,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

I want `(type,refid)` to be a unique key, but only if `type` is `single`. This can't be done with conventional keys, so I figured I would use a Trigger to detect insertion of a row, check if `type='single'`, look for a row with `type='single' and refid=new.refid`, and throw a duplicate entry error if one is found.

I'm using MySQL 5.5, so `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` is available to me. Can I use this to fire a Duplicate Key error in order to process the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` part of the query, and if so, how?

As an alternative, I could update the row in the Trigger and return a generic error condition, but I think it would be nicer (or at least more intuitive) to have `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`REPLACE INTO`. Derp! Forgot all about that.

Comment: I stumbled onto this because I'm trying to achieve the same thing (create a MySQL trigger that works with `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ...

Just be careful, semantically `REPLACE INTO` is not the same: `REPLACE INTO` does a `DELETE` then an `INSERT`, where `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` does an `UPDATE` ... if you have insert/update/delete triggers defined, you may find triggers executing that you didn't intend ...

Answer (score -1):

Try below trigger. I am not that good in writing triggers. I have not executed the code below. You can use this as a prototype.

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkDuplicateEntry
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF type, ref_id ON employees
   DECLARE @duplicateCount INT;
   FOR EACH ROW
   IF ( new.type <> 'single' )
        BEGIN
           @duplicateCount = count(*) from yourTableName where type = 'single' AND refid = new.refid
        END;

   IF ( duplicateCount  > 0 )
        BEGIN
             SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
             SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate Entry';
        END
```

Comment: I don't think this will trigger `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: This will run each Before `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

Comment: I think not. In fact, this will trigger a syntax error. Twice over, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Actually i am not good in writing triggers :). I just want to give some logic.